# Failling installing NeuralProphet

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to install NeuralProphet package which as many dependancies.
I'm running it on Python 3.8.5  May it's  an python version issue  ?
Here are my errors:

```
$ pip install neuralprophet
Collecting neuralprophet
  Downloading neuralprophet-0.2.7-py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting attrdict>=2.0.1
  Downloading attrdict-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.4 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet) (1.1.4)
Collecting convertdate>=2.1.2
  Downloading convertdate-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Collecting holidays>=0.10.2
  Downloading holidays-0.10.4.tar.gz (120 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet) (2.8.1)
Collecting torch-lr-finder>=0.2.1
  Downloading torch_lr_finder-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets>=7.5.1
  Downloading ipywidgets-7.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting neuralprophet
  Downloading neuralprophet-0.2.6-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
  Downloading neuralprophet-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install neuralprophet==0.2.5, neuralprophet==0.2.6 and neuralprophet==0.2.7 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    neuralprophet 0.2.7 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0
    neuralprophet 0.2.6 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0
    neuralprophet 0.2.5 depends on torch<1.7.0 and >=1.4.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Moreover I have download the repository from Github and did the install step from the package documentation as follow : http://neuralprophet.com/
I have these errors  when I write the pip install command:

```
GMU@GMU-PORT MINGW64 ~/desktop/programmation_1/Tests_Articles/neural_prophet (master)
$ pip install .
Processing c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation_1\tests_articles\neural_prophet
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting torch-lr-finder>=0.2.1
  Using cached torch_lr_finder-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting LunarCalendar>=0.0.9
  Downloading LunarCalendar-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.0 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet==0.2.8) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet==0.2.8) (1.19.2)
Collecting ipywidgets>=7.5.1
  Using cached ipywidgets-7.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\users\gmu\desktop\programmation\lib\site-packages (from neuralprophet==0.2.8) (3.3.2)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.4.0 (from neuralprophet)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.4.0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am having a similar problem: I installed CUDA 11.1 and torch 1.8.0 as per the pytorch installation instructions.  I am using python 3.7.3 and have installed NVIDIA Nsight 2020.3.1.21012.  I have an NVIDIA RTX 2080 (mobile) GPU.  I get the following error message when attempting pip install neuralprophet:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch<1.7.0,>=1.4.0 (from neuralprophet[live]) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.8.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<1.7.0,>=1.4.0 (from neuralprophet[live])

Comment: No mention in the documentation that torch >= 1.7.0 is not supported.  But that would seem to be what the error message says? torch must be >= 1.4.0 and < 1.7.0.  That also seems to mean that CUDA >=11 can't be used.

Comment: Hi Carl. I found that my Python version was a 32 bit and it seems that pytorch needs a 64 bit version. For me it worked. So let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I downgraded my pytorch to 1.6.9 (I think), the highest version that lay within the range > 1.4.0 and <1.7.0 and now it work.  That also involved downgrading my Cuda as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have encountered many difficulties to install the package including:

1. Upgrade from 3.6 to 3.8 -> downgrade to 3.7
2. Install it through Git Bash but the main environment in my laptop is 3.6 / although i have both 3.7 and 3.8 envs couldn't change to one of them

Found the solution which would apply to some as well:

```
!pip3 install git+https://github.com/ourownstory/neural_prophet.git#egg=neuralprophet
```